# How to test Quasar (as Vue CLI plugin)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, quasar-framework

I have Vue project and I use [Quasar Framework](https://quasar.dev/) here. The last one I use as [Vue CLI Plugin](https://quasar.dev/start/vue-cli-plugin) and it works perfect ([code repo](https://github.com/zvadym/vue-todo) and [live url](https://zvadym-vue-todo.firebaseapp.com/)).

Now I want to add some unit tests to my project (using jest) and I encountered a problem I did not understand..

I try to write a simple test for [NetworkWatcher](https://github.com/zvadym/vue-todo/blob/master/src/components/NetworkWatcher.vue) component. This component uses `QIcon` component and I have to import it in my test:

```js
import { Quasar, QIcon } from "quasar";
import NetworkWatcher from "@/components/NetworkWatcher.vue";

const localVue = createLocalVue();

localVue.use(Vuex);
localVue.use(Quasar, { components: { QIcon } });

describe("NetworkWatcher.vue", () => {});
```

In this case I have an error:

[image]

After some experiments and searching I tried next

```js
import * as AllQuasar from "quasar";
const { Quasar } = AllQuasar;

const components = Object.keys(AllQuasar).reduce((object, key) => {
  const val = AllQuasar[key];
  if (val && val.component && val.component.name != null) {
    object[key] = val;
  }
  return object;
}, {});

const localVue = createLocalVue();

localVue.use(Vuex);
localVue.use(Quasar, { components });
```

And it works, I can go this way.. but I don't like it. It seems to be wrong! So why the first way doesn't work?

I know what Quasar has a good documentation for "Quasar CLI" version and even has it's own test runner. But I want to use "Vue CLI plugin" version.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code below, as it's not able to resolve the quasar dependency properly.

```
import { Quasar, QIcon } from "quasar-framework/dist/quasar.mat.esm"; //this line is modified 
import NetworkWatcher from "@/components/NetworkWatcher.vue";

const localVue = createLocalVue();

localVue.use(Vuex);
localVue.use(Quasar, { components: { QIcon } });

describe("NetworkWatcher.vue", () => {});
```

Comment: I don't have `quasar-framework` package. In my `node_modules` it is called `quasar`, but there is no `quasar.mat.esm` inside `dist`